# can't open xml file on android

Tags: android, xml, resources, jdom

I am working on an android application in which I want to parse an xml file as a local resource. I use jdom to parse it, but I have a probleme, I can not open the file and I don't know why. The error is at this line :

```
document = builder.build(new File("res/xml/data.xml"));
```

The file is located into the folder res/xml of my project. I got this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't open file:/res/xml/data.xml
Caused by java.io.FileNotFoundException :res/xml/data.xml
```

I tried this:

```
document = builder.build(new File("data.xml"));
```

but it did not work. I don't know why the file is not found.

Would you have an idea?

Thanks in advance

---

Thank you for your suggestion. The 'Uri path' works but not the line

```
document = builder.build(new File(path));
```

The method class File must have a type entree String. I tried this:

```
document = builder.build(new File(path.getPath());
```

but it returned null and

```
document = builder.build(new File(path.toString());
```

I got the same error. Would you have an idea ?
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will need to use an URI in your file constructor that points to the data.xml file.

Try something like this:

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.here/" + R.xml.data);
document = builder.build(new File(path));
```

This tutorial here might also be helpful: http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html

Answer (score 1):

If this is a resource inside your application then you should use Resources methods suchas getXml(). You can get an instance of the rources class from the Context object

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

document = builder.build(br);
```

Be sure to put the data.xml in the res/raw-folder.